# How do I get a DataRow from a row in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I'm using a databound Windows Forms `DataGridView`. how do I go from a user selected row in the `DataGridView` to the `DataRow` of the `DataTable` that is its source?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem).Row
```

Assuming you've bound an ordinary `DataTable`.

```
MyTypedDataRow row = (MyTypedDataRow)((DataRowView)DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem).Row
```

Assuming you've bound a typed datatable.

See the [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wszzzc7.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks.  On a related question; how do I type my rows?

Comment: You need to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(VS.71).aspx.  However, I'd recommend ignoring them and moving onto LINQ to SQL if you haven't already done so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Comment: Lovely solution! works like a charm, I used in this way:
((dgvAttached.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row as DataRow)

Answer (score 10):

```
DataTable table = grdMyGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row = ((DataRowView)grdMyGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).Row;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a `DataGridViewRow` is a property called `DataBoundItem` of type object.

This will contain a `DataRowView` (for certainty you can check this)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 .NET 4.5, I had success with

```
 var row = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;
```

Comment: This is ASP.Net, not WinForms.