# Sort Datagridview and change the value effect different row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have data table with data. I am assigning it as data source to the datagridview. after that i am sorting the datagridview by clicking column header. after that i am selecting two lines and changing the value through coding in datatable using selected row index. but its changing different column in datagridiveiew.

Comment: My magic 8 ball says you are assigning the value to the wrong column. Show how you are assigning these new values. You may want to view the following: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the logic and the code which i used to assign value in data table is correct. I think the problem is in sorting the datagridview. according to me the selected row after sorting in the datagridview and the datatable are different

Comment: You are correct. The `DataGridView` and the `DataTable` it is bound to may not have the same row indexes. When getting the data from a selected row in the DataGridView that is bound to a table, you need to get the index of the `DataBoundItem` for the selected row. You do specify how you are getting the new data and assigning it to the table, so speculation is the best you may get.

Comment: @JohnG can you explain how to get the index of databounditem or can you explain if i want to change the value of the cell which in databounditem

Comment: There are a lot of examples for this `DataBoundItem`... google is your friend. Try something and if it doesn't work post it here. If you showed the code where you are doing this, then it may be easier, however since there is no code google it.

Comment: sorry i couldn't find any solution for it on google. i can get the databounditem and i am changing the value how can i reassign that object to that particular databounditem row

Comment: Without code to see what you are doing… there isn’t much anyone can do. Not sure what you searched for earlier… using a google search of C# `DataTable` `DataGridView` `DataBoundItem` turned up 4000+ hits… the First one was this link. [How do I get a DataRow from a row in a DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822314/how-do-i-get-a-datarow-from-a-row-in-a-datagridview).

Comment: thnx for your effort and the reply @JohnG I stoped that and found different solution thnx for your help bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing datatable I changed value of datagridview cell. Its worked