# How to get filtered row index after applying RowFilter to DataView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, dataview

I'm designing a tool to display all log records in a DataGridView. The logs are stored chronologically in a DataTable `dt`. Logs have three types of Severity: Error, Info and Verbose.

Log lines are also grouped by activities. So along with this DataTable there is also List associated. For each Activity I store the first line number and last line number in DataTable `dt`.

The feature I'm having difficulty with is to jump to first lines corresponding to selected activity but filtered by Severity, e.g. display only Error log lines and jump to the first Error line in selected activity. I'm trying to use:

```cs
logGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectedActivity.ActivityStartLine;
(logGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Severity >= " + severity;
```

However, this code does not work for Severity Error and Info, as the log lines have been filtered, the original index of `selectedActivity.ActivityStartLine` no longer makes sense in new filtered list of logs. How can I get the new index after filter has been applied and jump to that line instead?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=netcore-3.1) … documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a DataRow from a row in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822314/how-do-i-get-a-datarow-from-a-row-in-a-datagridview)