# Unable to update DGV selectedRow on SQLite DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

I can't seem to update the correct selected row in my DataGridView using SQLite.

Pardon, if this doesn't make sense.

I'm Building a "loaner device" (i.e. laptops, tablets, phones, etc.) tracking app. The devices are stored in a SQLite DB. I can pull the devices that have been loaned out into a DGV (using an OnLoan column with "yes" values). I want to change the OnLoan value to "no" (which effectivly "removes" it from the list) when highlighting a row and clicking a "Check in" button.

As of now, the button click connects to the DB and runs an UPDATE command that changes the value of the cell from "yes" to "no". The DGV is then updated.

However, I'm not sure what to set for a WHERE clause on my SQL statement.
I tried using the currentRow index, but as the currentRow index isn't necessarily the same as the Id (PK column set to auto increment) on the SQL DB, it caused all sorts of issues.

Now I can change the value of the cell in question on the DGV with no issues, however, it doesn't update it on the DB.

Here is my current code:

```
    private void CheckInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //connection to SQLite DB
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DeviceOnLoanTable.SelectedRows)
            {
                string query = "UPDATE Device SET OnLoan = 'No' WHERE Id = " + DeviceOnLoanTable.CurrentRow.Index + ";";

                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    LoadOnLoan(); //re-queries the DB for devices that are still on loan  
                                  //(i.e. "yes" in the OnLoan column)
                    DeviceOnLoanTable.Refresh();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously the `DeviceOnLoanTable.CurrentRow.Index` is not the correct way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.
I thought it might be better to update the DGV, then push that to the DB, but not sure how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you initially get the data from the DB, are you getting the ID? It appears obvious you are going to need it if you want to update “that” ID’s values.

Comment: @JohnG I'm not pulling it as part of the query no. But even if it's not part of the query for the DGV you can still use it in an UPDATE statement. What I need to do is match the selected row to the device in question, whether that is through the Id or another value.

Comment: _”But even if it's not part of the query for the DGV you can still use it in an UPDATE statement.”_ ? ... How can you “use” something you don’t have? Where are you getting the ID? If there are other “unique” identifiers then, yes, you could use them, however, from your question and code, it is specifically trying to “update” a row “where” the ID = XX. But you don’t have XX, so I am not understanding how you plan to use it when you do not have it.

Comment: @JohnG the thought just occured to me. I should be able to use the device name as the common point. Something like: `WHERE DeviceName = DeviceOnLoan.SelectedRow.Cells[0]` thus if the device name matches the value in cell 0 (which is the index of the device name) it'll change the OnLoan value to No. Right?

Comment: @JohnG to answer your previous question: the ID column is the Primary Key in the DB that auto increments with each new row (device) added. Thus, each device has its own unique ID in the DB. So even if that column isn't part of the original query it still is in the DB

Comment: If there is ONLY ONE (1) device name for each row… then, yes that will work. However, if two (2) or more rows have the same device name, then the query will update those also. If you want to “update” ALL devices of type XX or a single device XX will dictate if you need an ID. I am guessing that the ID is the only field that will “uniquely identify” a “single” row.

Comment: The ID in the DB is not going to help here. This is what you are describing… since the ID is NOT present in the grid (visible or not), then how are you going to identify which row in the grid…. Goes to which row in the DB?

Comment: `DeviceOnLoanTable.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem` gives you the original row from your query. It might contain what you need (e.g. use the device name from there instead of directly from the grid). You might also change your query to return the ID which you could then retrieve from `DataBoundItem` without displaying it in the grid. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822314/how-do-i-get-a-datarow-from-a-row-in-a-datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.
In the original query to populate the table, I included the Id column, then hid it with

```
this.DeviceOnLoanTable.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
```

Then I changed my update statement to:

```
string query = "UPDATE Device SET OnLoan = 'No' WHERE Id = " + DeviceOnLoanTable.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + ";";
```

Thus, the Id == The value in the current cell (i.e. the Id of the record I wanted to update).

Works like a charm!